# ASP.NET validators

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

i am using asp.net validators for validating simple fields like blank textboxes (e.g. login page).
my problem is when i am submitting blank fields,the validators are giving correct output.
and in second step, when i entered incorrect username the label where i have given error message of username is getting displayed along with blank validation message of validators.

means along with label which is visible=false by default is getting true even if there is blank field.

i wrote all .cs code in `if (Page.IsValid) { }`

Answer (score 2):

You can use RequiredFieldvalidator for the blank fields. You set the ControlToValidate property to the id of the control you wish to validate

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server"
    id="ReqFldVal1" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" />
```

Comment: also you may use Page.Validate() method in code to validate page against the validators on page...